# I can not get user's data from my firebase database in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my database structure is : rootNode->node1->Uid->RandomId(which i get from push.getKey() method) then my data->(name, email , phone)

```
projectName:
     SampleUsers
           Uid
              RandomKey1(i get this random key by push.getKey() method)
                         Name : User1
                         Email : user@email.com
                         Phone : +1234567890
              RandomKey2
                         Name : User1
                         Email : user@email.com
                         Phone : +1234567890
```

I want to show users detail in his profile page when user login . But i can not get that random key ;

```
mUserRef =  firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple child nodes under each user? Why not just have `/SampleUsers/Uid/Name: "Machine Learning"`?

Comment: because i want to store each user's info inside SampleUsers node. when user will signup/login his Uid node will add in SampleUsers Node and then whenEver he will enter any details it will stores inside his Uid node . @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that is not clear to me. Can you add the actual JSON you want to your question?

Comment: drive.google.com/file/d/1K74KYkfmJfVsMyjviEtEOhO7qOBTl4eE/… json file link . i want to print products nodes uid's data . we can get that uid when user will login . then for that uid there are some nodes with random keys , i want to print that data from each and every random key's of that specific uid . Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

To show all child nodes of a given snapshot, iterate over `DataSnapshot.getChildren()`. So for example:

```
DatabaseReference userRef =  firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey()); // the push ID
            System.out.println(childSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wan to print all details of Uid node's each random node like: -   Name : User1 ,Email: user1@email.com , Phone : +1234567890. ; Name : User2 , Email : user2@email.com , Phone : +23840238408 ....... so on

Comment: Did you run the code I gave in my answer? What does it do?